# Functions with the same signature in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Consider the function `setup_per_cpu_areas`. There is one definition in architecture specific code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/kernel/setup_percpu.c#L166. There is another one defined in architecture independent code here:https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/mm/percpu.c#L2665 or here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/mm/percpu.c#L2696.

After the kernel is built which one is used in the kernel image? There are a lot of such cases in kernel source code, so in general what's the purpose of such a pattern?

Comment: They're conditional. The kernel has a config tool. It would depend on the target.

Comment: @polarysekt I don't think the one in setup_percpu.c is under a config. The one in percpu.c is.

Answer (score 3):

The first one you cite is an x86-arch-specific version. The `.config` for the x86 architecture defines the preprocessor symbol `CONFIG_HAVE_SETUP_PER_CPU_AREA`. And note that the second link you cited is used when that symbol is *not* defined. (The third version is used when `CONFIG_SMP` is not defined, and so would also not be applied for this x86 configuration.)

The linux kernel has a fairly complex and robust configuration system built into it. See the files named `Kconfig` that are sprinkled throughout the kernel source tree. In particular, `arch/x86/Kconfig` has this nugget:

```
config HAVE_SETUP_PER_CPU_AREA
        def_bool y
```

That basically says "unconditionally define the `HAVE_SETUP_PER_CPU_AREA` symbol to True when you build x86".

In summary, the settings in your kernel `.config` file select many features and sometimes deselect others by defining or not defining symbols. Those symbols are used in choosing which code is compiled and linked in. Some of the settings are under your control (try `make menuconfig` to see those); others are specified by the per-architecture defaults.

EDIT:
If `CONFIG_SMP` is not enabled, this setting in `arch/x86/kernel/Makefile` prevents the x86-specific `setup_per_cpu_areas` from being included:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_SMP)               += setup_percpu.o
```

The kernel makefile system turns that into `obj-n` or `obj-y` according to the definition of `CONFIG_SMP`.

Comment: What will happen if CONFIG_SMP is not defined? I don't see a reason why that need to be defined for x86. The x86 arch specific definition is not under a pre-processor flag. If CONFIG_SMP is not defined then there will be two definitions in the kernel.

Comment: "The x86 arch specific definition is not under a pre-processor flag." Everything under arch-specific directories is conditionally compiled (it's used if the architecture we are targeting matches the one of the directory).

Comment: See my edit. It's worth spending some time to understand the kernel build system. It's very powerful and plays a major role in deciding what gets compiled for a particular configuration. See `Documentation/kbuild/*` (starting with `makefiles.txt`).